# Getting null reference in second function inside if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

The first function works, but I get null in the second functions console.log for currentError.
I have tried adding console.log in varius places.
Maybe I need a forEach for the currentError by using querySelectorAll for all the span elements that are immediate siblings, or use an attribute selector?

```
formInputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("blur", (event) => {
    
    input = event.currentTarget;
    let currentError = input.nextElementSibling;    

    if (
      input.validity.valid ||
      currentError.classList.contains("error")
    ) {
      currentError.textContent = "";
      currentError.classList.remove("error");
      input.classList.remove("error");
      return;
    } else {
      typeMismatchError(input, currentError);
    }
    return;
  });
});

contactForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  formInputs.forEach((input) => {
    console.log(input);
    console.log(input.nextElementSibling);
    let currentError = input.nextElementSibling;
    

    if (
      input.validity.valid ||
      currentError.classList.contains("error")
    ) {
      console.log(currentError.textContent);
      currentError.textContent = "";
      currentError.classList.remove("error");
      input.classList.remove("error");
      return;
    } else {
      requiredError(input, currentError);
    }
    return;
  });
  // Then we prevent the form from being sent by canceling the event
  event.preventDefault();
  return;
});
```

Here is the html.

```
<form novalidate action="contact.html" method="post" class="form">
        <!----input type="hidden" name="workmail" value="" -->
        <!--The HTML and XHTML specifications allow both implicit and explicit labels. However, some assistive technologies do not correctly handle implicit labels so do not put input inside label, and use for attribute in the label and an associated id in the input.
          https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/H44
        -->
        <label for="name">Name: Please add your full name<span></span></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" required />
        <span aria-live="polite">(required)&#10059;</span>

        <label for="email">Email: Please add a valid email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" required />
        <span aria-live="polite">(required)&#10059;</span>

        <label for="subject">Subject: Please add a descriptive subject</label>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="" required />
        <span aria-live="polite">(required)&#10059;</span>

        <label for="text">Message: </label>
        <textarea id="text" name="text" value=""></textarea>
        <span aria-live="polite"></span>

        <input type="submit" value="Send Contact Inquiry" />
      </form>
```

Comment: You could check to see if currentError exists before using it:  `if (currentError) { // it exists}`.  If it doesn’t exist there was no nextElementSibling.